# Delete rows based on duplicates AND dates (pandas)

Tags: pandas, date

I have a dataframe as such:

```
df = """
    doc_id      X1    Y1  Z1        Date
2  33075059515  30x   RU  5         2014-01-15T00:00:00Z    
3  53075235984  50x   RU  6         2011-01-09T00:00:00Z
4  28865465787  30x   RU  NaN       2014-01-23T00:00:00Z    
5  28865465787  30x   SO  5         2021-06-03T12:00:00Z    
6  28865465787  50x   SO  4         2011-02-03T00:00:00Z
8  87652548931  50x   SO  NaN       2016-10-27T12:00:00Z
```

I would like to delete a row only when it is a duplicate of another row in column X1 and Y1 AND when it has a date in the 'Date' column that is within 4 weeks of another row.

The hope is for it to look like this:

```
df = """
    doc_id      X1    Y1  Z1        Date
2  33075059515  30x   RU  5         2014-01-15T00:00:00Z    
3  53075235984  50x   RU  6         2011-01-09T00:00:00Z
5  28865465787  30x   SO  5         2021-06-03T12:00:00Z    
6  28865465787  50x   SO  4         2011-02-03T00:00:00Z
8  87652548931  50x   SO  NaN       2016-10-27T12:00:00Z
```

Deleting duplicates for column X1 and Y1 is simple, but I cannot figure out how to combine it with a rolling 4 week window for the date.

EDIT as per Mozway's request. This is a new example of the input:

```
    doc_id      X1    Y1  Z1        Date
1  68754534654  30x   RU  5         2014-01-14T00:00:00Z
2  33075059515  30x   RU  5         2014-01-15T00:00:00Z    
3  53075235984  50x   RU  6         2011-01-09T00:00:00Z
4  28865465787  30x   RU  NaN       2014-01-23T00:00:00Z    
5  28865465787  30x   SO  5         2021-06-03T12:00:00Z    
6  28865465787  50x   SO  4         2011-02-03T00:00:00Z
7  78764599568  50x   SO  NaN       2016-10-27T12:00:00Z
8  87652548931  50x   SO  NaN       2016-10-27T12:00:00Z
```

Here an example of the output I am getting which is not yet the desired output (the rows in bold should also have been removed):

```
    doc_id      X1    Y1  Z1        Date
1  68754534654  30x   RU  5         2014-01-14T00:00:00Z    
3  53075235984  50x   RU  6         2011-01-09T00:00:00Z
**4  28865465787  30x   RU  NaN       2014-01-23T00:00:00Z**    
5  28865465787  30x   SO  5         2021-06-03T12:00:00Z
6  28865465787  50x   SO  4         2011-02-03T00:00:00Z    
7  78764599568  50x   SO  NaN       2016-10-27T12:00:00Z
**8  87652548931  50x   SO  NaN       2016-10-27T12:00:00Z**
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to identify which rows have a match on the two keys within the threshold, then [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = (df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
         .sort_values(by='Date').reset_index()
      )

keep = (pd.merge_asof(df2, df2, on='Date', by=['X1', 'Y1'], suffixes=(None, '_'),
                      allow_exact_matches=False, tolerance=pd.Timedelta('4W'))
          .set_index('index')
          ['index_'].isna()
       )

out = df[keep]
```

Output:

```
        doc_id   X1  Y1   Z1                      Date
2  33075059515  30x  RU  5.0 2014-01-15 00:00:00+00:00
3  53075235984  50x  RU  6.0 2011-01-09 00:00:00+00:00
5  28865465787  30x  SO  5.0 2021-06-03 12:00:00+00:00
6  28865465787  50x  SO  4.0 2011-02-03 00:00:00+00:00
8  87652548931  50x  SO  NaN 2016-10-27 12:00:00+00:00
```

Intermediate `keep`:

```
index
3     True
6     True
2     True
4    False
8     True
5     True
Name: doc_id_, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Something is not right with the final line of code. Error: 'Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).'

Comment: do you have duplicated indices in the original index? Can you provide an example that reproduces the error?

Comment: Hi mozway! I was able to fix that error, but I in fact noticed two other complications I wanted to ask you about. 1) If the dates are the exact same, the current code is keeping both (I would like to keep just one). 2) If there are more than two rows with the same values in X1 and Y1 and date in the 'Date' column within 4 weeks of another, I think only one gets deleted (and the other rows remain). Do you have an idea on how to solve it? The first issue I could do (not elegant but) by just dropping duplicates in a new line of code

Comment: Can you provide an example (as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75684807/16343464) to your question) with the input/output?

Comment: I did! Hopefully it makes sense. Sorry, one of my first posts on here.

Answer (score 0):

Mozway's answer worked for the most part. I had to change the final line of code. In total, this is the code that worked:

df2 = (df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
.sort_values(by='Date').reset_index()
)

keep = (pd.merge_asof(df2, df2, on='Date', by=['X1', 'Y1'], suffixes=(None, '*'), allow_exact_matches=False, tolerance= pd.Timedelta('4W')).set_index('index')['index*'].isna())

out = df2[keep.reindex(df2.index, fill_value=False)]